# Import a web page with $\LaTeX$ code including images (png or other)

Tags: image-processing, import, latex, webmathematica

To be brief; I would like to import a web page, so I use

`Import["http://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/lecture-32-the-malliavin-derivative/"];`

which gives a notebook file without any png images in $\LaTeX$ code.
Is there any way to load the images in $\LaTeX$ script, by exploring the source code for example?

Comment: Yes; that is exactly what you need to do. You need to use `Cases` or similar to extract the source code corresponding to the text, then you need to replace every occurrence of every img-tag with its alt or title attribute.

Comment: thank you for your help. What is the correct script with Cases and Import